# Can't find managedQuery

Tags: android

Just trying out a couple of Android samples.   Struggling to find the method *managedQuery*

Compiler keeps reporting:

```
The method `managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)` in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments `(Uri, String[], null, String)`
```

Is this because it's deprecated?  Thought I would just get a warning for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* deprecated, but the reason why you see that error is simply that your parameters don't match up with the arguments. Exactly as the error says, you're giving it:

```
(Uri, String[], null, String)
```

and it expects

```
(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)
```

You have 4, it expects 5.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't pass correct number of parameters, you will get ....not applicable for the arguments... error.

```
managedQuery(Uri, String[], String, String[], String)
```

You need to have another parameter, it should look like: `(Uri, String[], null, null/String[], String)`